# Can we open again Firebase Popup notification after user selected his choice

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, browser, firebase-cloud-messaging

Basically i have a requirement that I have to open firebase permissions popup when user check or uncheck notification_settings box in my webapp.

But if user already selected his choice on firebase notifications popup I can open it from code unless user reset his browser permissions.

Is there a way to open that again so user select his choice again?

I write this method for it

```
requestNotificationPermission() {
  Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      console.log('Notification permission granted')

      // Obtain FCM token again
      const messaging = getMessaging()
      getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'BKhPAgdtefFrvowpm3CcQdRv--fBa-bDRwdPMQqPxCfs3shHiiwOEPqghKd9LDtNj87nNBuF7NdM7JNBt-TjTkc' }).then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
          console.log('FCM Token:', currentToken)
          // Do something with the FCM token
        } else {
          console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.')
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err)
      })
    } else {
      console.log('Notification permission denied')
      // Handle the case where permission is denied
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: If a user has decided not to allow push notifications, then that is their choice. THEY can change the permission if they want.

Comment: What do you mean by "Firebase notifications popup"? The browser is responsible for collecting and enforcing permissions from the end user, not Firebase.

Comment: @JaromandaX can we ask him to select his choice again?

Comment: no, you can ask her to change her settings if she wants, but you can't make that browser popup come up again through code